# fading between tabs with javascript/css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fade

I have this pre-made code with tabs in it, and I want a fade/transition effect to happen when you click between tabs. I've already seen several answers and tutorials for this method, but:
I just have no idea on how to do it without destroying the code that is already there, as in: where exactly do I put the right commands and what do I change?
Here is a fiddle website with all of the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/dr6pqy23/).
This is the parts that (I think) are relevant from the css:

```
.tabs {
    position: relative;   
    min-height: 400px;
    width: 496px; 
    clear: both;
    margin: 25px 0;
}

.tab {
    float: left;
}

.tab label {
    background: #E3DFD6;
    padding: 20px 10px; 
    margin-left: -1px; 
    font-family: icons;
    position: relative;
    left: 1px;
    color: #C7636D;
}

.tab [type=radio] {
    display: none;   
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    left: 0;
    background: white;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
    background: white;
    z-index: 2;
    color: #6898A7;
}

[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

from the html:

```
/* menu */
  </style></head><body><div id="content"><div class="tabs"><div class="tab"><input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked><label for="tab-1"><span class="icon" title="my profile">title</span></label>
  <div class="content"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/nqcm3ld/iXnn711di/about.png"><div style="float: right; width: 242px; padding: 10px; text-align: justify;"><h1>Sephi Satou;</h1><div style="width: 241px; height: 280px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; padding: 3px; text-align: justify;"> text </div></div></div> 
   </div>
   <div class="tab"><input type="radio" id="tab-7" name="tab-group-1"><label for="tab-7"><span class="icon" title="about me">title2</span></label>
   <div class="content"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/nqcm3ld/Cx5n71a09/about2.png" align="right" style="margin-right: 15px;"><div style="float: left; margin-left: -15px; width: 230px; padding: 10px; text-align: justify;"><h1>More about me;</h1><div style="width: 241px; height: 280px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; padding: 3px; text-align: justify;"> text </div></div></div></div>
               <div class="tab"><input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1"><label for="tab-2"><span class="icon" title="find me">title3</span></label><div class="content"><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><h1>onde me encontrar</h1><br><center><a href=""><span class="social">u</span></a><a href=""><span class="social">v</span></a><a href=""><span class="social">ą</span></a><a href=""><span class="social">Ć</span></a><a href=""><span class="social">ć</span></a><a href=""><span class="social">Ĵ</span></a></center></div>
            <div class="tab"><input type="radio" id="tab-6" name="tab-group-1"><label for="tab-6"><span class="icon" title="'music's i like">title4</span></label><div class="content"><h1>what i listen</h1><div style="width: 450px; margin-top: 25px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 285px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/nqcm3ld/zAwn71buz/cd1.png" width="100"> 
   <div style="float: right; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 25px;"><h3>Album: Tingaralatingadun</h3><div class="artista">
                   tuatha de damm
               </div> 
   </div></div></div> 
   </div>   


            <div class="tab"><input type="radio" id="tab-5" name="tab-group-1"><label for="tab-5"><span class="icon" title="books i like">title5</span></label><div class="content"><h1>Fave Books</h1><div style="width: 450px; margin-top: 25px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 285px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/nqcm3ld/9iPn71dsq/lv1.png"><div style="float: right; width: 340px;"><h2>Immortal Hearts</h2><div class="artista">
                   Ellen Schreiber
               </div> 
               <div class="saga">
                   saga: Vampire Kisses 
               </div><p>description </p>
               </div>
```

and from the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

}
    (function(){
        var analytics_frame = document.getElementById('ga_target');
        var analytics_iframe_loaded;
        var user_logged_in;
        var blog_is_nsfw = 'No';
        var addthis_enabled = true;
```

Comment: If you cut your code down to the bare minimum required and post it here and maybe a link to a fiddle for others to work on you'll get more responses :) https://codepen.io/ and https://jsfiddle.net/ are two popular options.

Comment: i've put the part of the code where i am having trouble and a link for the fiddle website now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic method to fade between active buttons and their corresponding 'tabs' using jQuery to add/remove classes and css for the styling.

The transitional styling is done by adding an `.active` class to the active/focused button (the button clicked)

The transition speed is set in the css classes `.button.` and `.container`

Make sure that in your html the `.button` and corresponding `.content` divs that you want to show on page load both have the class `.active`

### **jQuery Explained**

When a new button is clicked we do a few things..

**1. `$('.button.active').removeClass('active');`**

We `removeClass` `.active` on the active button

**2. `$(this).addClass('active');`**

We then add the `.active` class to the button we've clicked using jQuery's [(this)](http://html-tuts.com/jquery-this-selector/) selector.

**3. `$('.content.active').removeClass('active');`**

We remove the `.active` class from the active `.content` div the same way we did with the button in step 1.

**4. `var tabNumber = $(this).attr('data-tab');`**

We create a variable 'tabNumber' to hold the `data-tab` value. data-tab is an attribute we create to match the buttons with the corresponding tabs. Clicking a button with the `data-tab="1"` will open the .container with `data-tab="1"`. The value doesn't have to be a number. You can have data-tab="about" as long as you match both `.button` and `.container`.

**5. `var tabToOpen = ".content[data-tab='" + tabNumber + "']";`**

Here we've put our selector into a variable so that our next line of code looks prettier. Purely a coding style choice.

```
$(".content[data-tab='" + tabNumber + "']").addClass('active');
```

*vs*

```
$(tabToOpen).addClass('active');
```

The above should both do the same thing.

We find the correct `.content` div by using the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

**6. `$(tabToOpen).addClass('active');`**

Finally we add the active class to the `.container` which matches up with the `.button` we've clicked.

### **More**

If there are buttons you want to exclude you can use the css [:not](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp) selector or jQuery's [.not](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Instead of using classes you can also use jQuery to add inline styles with .css instead of [.addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)/[.removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Also look into [.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), a little more complex but the callback function can be useful for more complicated animations. You can see a working example in my [latest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43991844/3377049).

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
  $('.button.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.content.active').removeClass('active');
  var tabNumber = $(this).attr('data-tab');
  var tabToOpen = ".content[data-tab='" + tabNumber + "']"; 
  $(tabToOpen).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}
.button-container {
  display: flex;
}
.button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: hsl(0, 49.3%, 44.1%);
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.6s linear;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button.active {
  background-color: hsl(0, 70.6%, 45.3%);
}
.content-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.6s linear;
}
.content.active {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}
/* styling to show transition*/
.content:nth-child(1) {background-color: hsl(27.4, 65%, 48.2%);}
.content:nth-child(2) {background-color: hsl(173.6, 54.4%, 40.4%);}
.content:nth-child(3) {background-color: hsl(285.2, 37.7%, 57.8%);}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="button-container">
    <div class="button active" data-tab="1">Button 1</div>
    <div class="button" data-tab="2">Button 2</div>
    <div class="button" data-tab="3">Button 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-container">
    <div class="content active" data-tab="1">
      <h1>Content Area 1</h1>
      <p>something something something</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content" data-tab="2">
      <h1>2nd Content Area</h1>
      <p>words words words</p></div>
    <div class="content" data-tab="3">
      <h1>Area of Content III</h1>
      <p>stuff stuff stuff</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### **Play With It**

Here's the fiddle so you can test it out and play around with different transition ideas.

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/Lnsotzmx/

Comment: Fading between active buttons is my goal, but i'm Very new to coding and the usual instructions are just confusing, especially when i already have a code I just want to change, not create a new one. What exactly do I have to change/add to the code I provided, and where?

Comment: @Letícia We'd have to see your working code. Right now your codepen is not loading anything. If it's your own code you should be able to replicate just the buttons area of the page you're talking about. If you are able to post that somewhere that people can easily fiddle with you'll probably get more responses. As it is it's a lot of code to comb through and it's difficult to read (long lines to scroll through, etc.) and a lot of people will just skip over your question.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle website so it works and deleted parts from the code already in the post that we're useless so to make it easier and more approachable, is it better now?
Another problem I am having, probably from lack of clarification, is that I don't want just the _buttons_ to have a transition effect, but the tabs/boxes they open too.

Comment: @Letícia I posted a new answer, if that is the effect you want I will explain it later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this fade effect out..

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/dr6pqy23/5/

Here's the jQuery code..

```
$('input:radio').click(function() {
  $('.content').css({
    'opacity': '0',
    'zIndex': '0'
  });
  $(this).closest('.tab').find('.content').animate({
    opacity: 1,
    zIndex: 1
  }, 400, function() {
    //callback if needed, after animation completes
  });
})
```

Replace the first `.content` div with this..

```
<div class="content" style="opacity: 1; z-index: 1;">
```

That will show the first 'tab' and hide the others.

And replace these css entries..

```
 .content {
   position: absolute;
   top: 28px;
   left: 0;
   background: white;
   /* fundo do about */
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   padding: 20px;
   padding-right: 5px;
   opacity: 0;
   z-index: -1;
 }

 [type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {

 }
```

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted, thank you so much for your help!